# C++ SQLite Determine if Query Results In {null}

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm trying to build a function to determine if a query returns {null}. For some reason it always returns false. What am I doing wrong?

```
bool CC_Database::checkNullQuery(string query)
{
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query.c_str(), -1, &statement, 0) == SQLITE_NULL)
{
    cout << "null" << endl;
    return true;
} else {
    cout << "not null" << endl;
    return false;
}
}
```

Code used to call function

```
if (!db->checkNullQuery("SELECT MAX(Inventory_ID) FROM Inventory;")) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does the code print out "not null"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your query is run on an empty set, it does not return {null}, but a result table with one column and one row that contains the `NULL` value.
You have to fetch the value of that row to determine whether it is `NULL`.

(And you forgot to call sqlite3_finalize().)

Furthermore, you should not execute the query *twice* just to determine whether the result is empty or not.
Your `db.query` function should just handle `NULL` values correctly.

The following is a function that expects a query that returns a single number (as your `MAX` query) or `NULL`:

```
int CC_Database::singleNumberQuery(const string& query, bool& resultIsValid)
{
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    int result;

    resultIsValid = false;

    int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query.c_str(), -1, &stmt, NULL);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        printf("error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        // or throw an exception
        return -1;
    }

    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    if (rc != SQLITE_DONE && rc != SQLITE_ROW) {
        printf("error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        // or throw an exception
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        return -1;
    }

    if (rc == SQLITE_DONE) // no result
        result = -1;
    else if (sqlite3_column_type(stmt, 0) == SQLITE_NULL) // result is NULL
        result = -1;
    else { // some valid result
        result = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
        resultIsValid = true;
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

    return result;
}
```

(If `-1` cannot be a valid return value, you do not need the `resultIsValid` parameter.)

Comment: Thanks, I am very new to C++ and SQlite. I got this working, but had to remove the resultIsValid to make it work could you give me an example of how to use this with the resultIsValid? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When an SQL statement is successfully-executed, `sqlite3_prepare_v2` will return `SQLITE_OK`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would check for SQLITE_OK (as per the [sqlite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html)). If the response is not SQLITE_OK then you would call sqlite3_errmsg(database) to discover the error.

Obviously if you have no error then you can proceed to step through the resulting rows from your query with sqlite3_step(statement)

Comment: I tried SQLITE_OK first and since there are no errors it always reports successful as well the issue I am running into is an error that crashes my program when the query returns null and the results are sent to a vector.
Example 
vector<vector<string> > resultMax = db->query("SELECT MAX(Inventory_ID) FROM Inventory;");